# MS Word: Change Hebrew Niqqud color

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, hebrew

I'm trying to create a macro in MS Word to change the color of a subset of Hebrew niqqud.

Before getting to the macro, I am having some issues with getting the regular Find/Replace to work.

It looks like this:

[image]

In the find box is `([֣-֪])` (which is this range `([\u{05A3}-\u{05AA}])`.

In replace is the captured result, but with the font color updated.

MS Word will tell me it has made N replacements, but the color never changes.

- Macbook Air M1 using 12.4 (Monterey)
- MS Word v16.62
- SBL Hebrew as the font
- Hebrew text has a separate paragraph style
- Things I've tried:

  - testing the find text to make sure it works
  - select `Match Diacritics` (does nothing)
  - tried replacing consonants (those do work)

I've been able to accomplish this correctly in Mellel.

Comment: I'm not using a Mac - just the standard Windows version.  Is there an option to switch on **match wildcards** or something mentioning **regular expressions**.  You will need that if you are using [] otherwise it will try to match the square brackets

Comment: @cup the "use wildcards" option is set